# Next JS 13 server side page not showing latest fetch data upon being routed to that page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server, fetch

I have a Server Component in Next 13 which fetches some data using fetch api on and then renders it. However upon visiting this page by routing to it using next/navigation on a button click still shows old data. New data is populated only upon refreshing the page manually.

Code:

```
import Post from "./Post";
import NewPostBtn from "./NewPostBtn";

async function getPosts() {
  let res = await fetch("https://xyx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts/.json", {
    cache: "no-store",
    next: {
      revalidate: 1,
    },
  });
  let posts = await res.json();
  posts = Object.values(posts);
  posts = posts.filter((post) => post != null);
  return posts;
}

const PostWall = async () => {
  console.log("Rendered PostWall");
  let posts = await getPosts();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap p-5 gap-5">
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post post={post} />
      ))}

      <NewPostBtn />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostWall;
```

I tried using the cache-control and the revalidate params on fetch function but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm experiencing the same problem in a client component.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525342/nextjs-app-directory-always-caches-the-fetched-data-no-matter-which-option-has-b

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I have found the solution. And in my opinion, the documentation is kinda misleading.

In the documentation, they suggest use below in client components for no cache behaviour

```
await fetch("/api/myApiRoute", {
      cache: "no-store" // I also tried "no-cache",
    });
```

But this doesn't work, because you also have to put

```
export const revalidate = 10;
```

in "/api/myApiRout". I repeat, you don't put this line in your component beacuse if you do, it doesn't work. You put this line into your API route.jsx.

If you're using a server component, put above line into your server component.

After that, I'm able to see the updated data.

Comment: Just put this `{
    next: { revalidate: 10 },
  }` behind your "api/myApiRoute" as the second parameter of the fetch function and it shall work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use useState and useEffect

so your code can be

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
       const res = await getPosts();
       setPosts(res.json()); // You can change according to your response
    };
    fetchData().catch(console.error);
  }, []);

return (
  <div className='flex flex-wrap p-5 gap-5'>
      {
        posts.map(post=><Post post={post}/>)
      }

      <NewPostBtn />
  </div>
)
```

if there any variable which triggers change of your posts you can pass in dependency array in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
       const res = await getPosts();
       setPosts(res.json()); // You can change according to your response
    };
    fetchData().catch(console.error);
  }, [yourVariable]);
```

But you should really understands how react hooks work including useState and useEffects

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
I cannot use useEffect or useState in this page as it is mean to be a server component. Is there any way to do the samething inside a Server component?