# NextJS App directory always caches the fetched data no matter which option has been set for no-cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch, next.js13

So, I've tried every possible advice on the internet, still, fetched data is cached. I know it because I'm using a mongodb server, I add data to the server, I see the data on the server, but on the website the data is previous (before the NextJS project build). It doesn't show the new data from the database after the build, which made me think fetch is cached.

I tried below;

```
export const revalidate = 0;
export const fetchCache = "force-no-store";
await fetch("/api/myApiRoute", {
      cache: "no-store" // I also tried "no-cache",
    });
```

I am also refreshing page manually and using `router.refresh()`. Still, the data from fetch is cached.

How can I get the updated data, not cached one?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I have found the solution. And in my opinion, the documentation is kinda misleading.

In the documentation, they suggest use below in client components for no cache behaviour

```
await fetch("/api/myApiRoute", {
      cache: "no-store" // I also tried "no-cache",
    });
```

But this doesn't work, because you also have to put

```
export const revalidate = 10;
```

**in "/api/myApiRoute"**. I repeat, you **don't** put this line in your component beacuse if you do, it doesn't work. You put this line **into your API route.jsx**.

After that, I'm able to see the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

no cache should works. you can see the console shows cache missed when fetching in dev environment. (otherwise it shows hit)